# Can a Sephardi Jew use Yemenite-style Tzitzit?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, tzitzis, yemenite-temani

I'd like to ask if a sefardi Jew from Iberia can use Rambam/Temani tzitziyot instead of the classic Sephardic tying with the ridge.

*Edit* Reason why I'm asking is because of the rules against changing the family minhag. In this case, family minhag is a genuine mess, with the only other observant jew of the family using both askenazi and sephardic tying.

Comment: Ayit, [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing us your question! I'd like to remind you that if this question is of a practical nature to you, [you should not rely on Mi Yodeya for a ruling](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest, perhaps starting with our 100+ other [tag:tzitzis] questions.

Comment: What about a Persian Jew using a French style? Or any other permutation?

Comment: what makes you think that they can't?

Comment: If you're tying with techelet, then according to some authorities it might actually be preferable that you tie them according to the Rambam, both for Ashkenazim and Sephardim/Temanim. (R. Dov Lior wrote a written psak that both Ashkenazim and Sephardim should tie tzitzit according to the Rambam's method. If I can, I'll try to track down the psak, if it's online.) By the way, it would be a good idea to [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/81854/edit) your question and include why it might be bad for a Sephardi to tie his tzitzit like the Rambam.

Comment: First of all, Thank you all for the warm welcome!
I thought there was a rabbinical mandate against deviating from our father's minhag. I remember finding that when I read about nusach. 
@ezraI do use tekhelet, but I can't afford it on all my tzitziyot since even though I use Radzyner tekhelet, getting the strings past customs is a nightmare as they tend to disappear. On those I tie Raavad following breslov custom. Does R. Lior's psak referes to tekhelet alone, or also to plane white tzitziyot?
kotouty, thank you for the referance, although my hebrew is way too limited to understand it.

Comment: @AyitShmarya - I'm pretty sure he wrote the psak concerning techelet only. But then again I might be wrong...

Comment: @ezra Well, I went looking for it and only found a mention of said psak at http://tekhelet.com/tekhelet-tying-faq/ so yeah, it's probably tekhelet-only. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking if it is kosher, the answer is yes. See [SA OC 12](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%91). The length of the strings is enough in both minhagim.

If you are asking for the lechatechilla, there is more than one minhag for sepharadim and for Temanim, some people have no real minhag, some others follow a special group, such as yeshiva or chasidut. Each case is particular and needs consulting with a Rabbi.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of it being against halakha for any Sepharadi Jew to follow the practice of the Rambam. If the Yemenites can adopt the ruling of a Sephardic Rabbi, certainly Sephardic Jews can adopt the ruling of a Sephardic Rabbi.